# Tikz extra node before forest

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees, forest

I would like to combine a forest with some kind of variable initiation on top of the first node.

This is the code I currently have

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\forestset{
    default preamble={
        before typesetting nodes={
            !r.replace by={[, coordinate, append]}
        },
        where n children=0{
            tier=word,
        }{
            where n children=0{
            }{
                diamond, aspect=3,
            }
        },
        where level=1{}{
            if n=1{
                edge label={node[pos=.2, above] {yes}},
            }{
                edge label={node[pos=.2, above] {no}},
            }
        },
        for tree={ 
            edge+={thick, -Latex},%math content,
            s sep'+=0.3cm,
            %draw,
            thick,
            edge path'={ (!u) -| (.parent)},
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
    
        \begin{forest} 
            [{$a_i=a_{i-1}, (a_0=1)$}\\{$b_i=b_{i-1}, (b_0=1)$}, align=center, base=bottom
            [{$a_i=1$},draw
            [nothing,draw]
            [{$t_i>3$},draw
            [{$l_i > 10$},draw
            [{$x_i \in A$},draw % und zwischen 3 und 50 Zeichen
            [nothing,draw] 
            [{$z = 1$},draw
            [nothing,draw]
            [I am Lorde yayaya,draw]   
            ]
            ]
            [nothing,draw] 
            ]
            [{$Speeder_i=1$},draw]   
            ]
            ]
            ]
        \end{forest}
    
\end{document}
```

It looks like this
[image]

But it should look like this
[image]

Comment: `$ Speeder_i $`  is the same as `$ Spdr_ie^3 $`, i.e. the product of *S*, *p*, *d*, *e*, *e* and *e* and *rᵢ*. You maybe want to use `\mathit{Speeder}_i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upper `no` comes from your first option

```
before typesetting nodes={% I don't even know what that does …
  !r.replace by={[, coordinate, append]}
},
```

Just removing it removes the `no`. (I don't know what it does …)

Your now upper most node (the one with the `a_i` and `b_i` equation) has two problems:

1. It uses the `diamond` shape.

   We use

   ```
   where n children<=1{}{diamond, aspect=3}
   ```

   instead of where n children=0 because we only want the `diamond` shape when a node has 2 or more children. (I guess `where n children >=2{diamond, aspect=3}{}` should work, too.)
2. It connects to its child with the `-|` path you set via `edge path'`. The `-|` path operation doesn't work nicely with nodes that are vertically and too wide. This one even is exactly vertically.

   We will use

   ```
   where level> = 2{
     edge path'={ (!u) -| (.parent)}
   }{}
   ```

### Code

I've marked the changed lines with `%%%!`.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\forestset{
  default preamble={
%    before typesetting nodes={%%%! I don't even know what that does …
%      !r.replace by={[, coordinate, append]}
%    },
    where n children=0{
      tier=word,
    }{
      where n children< = 1{%%%! changed from where n children=0
      }{
          diamond, aspect=3,
      }
    },
    where level=1{}{
      if n=1{
          edge label={node[pos=.2, above] {yes}},
      }{
          edge label={node[pos=.2, above] {no}},
      }
    },
    for tree={ 
      edge+={thick, -Latex},%math content,
      s sep'+=0.3cm,
      %draw,
      thick,
      where level> = 2{%%%! added condition for edge path'
        edge path'={ (!u) -| (.parent)}
      }{},
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[{$a_i=a_{i-1}, (a_0=1)$}\\{$b_i=b_{i-1}, (b_0=1)$},
  align=center,
  yshift=1cm %%%! base=bottom removed (only one node on this level)
             %%%! and yshift=1cm added (to make the arrow longer)
  [{$a_i=1$}, draw
    [nothing, draw]
    [{$t_i>3$}, draw
      [{$l_i > 10$}, draw
        [{$x_i \in A$}, draw % und zwischen 3 und 50 Zeichen
          [nothing, draw]
          [{$z = 1$}, draw
            [nothing, draw]
            [I am Lorde yayaya, draw]
          ]
        ]
        [nothing, draw] 
      ]
      [{$Speeder_i=1$}, draw]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: If the Lorde node also contains only `nothing` then you will have the same problem with `-|` as with the root node because `z = 1` node is wider than the distance between the centers of its children.